# Pop-up notification at a specified time or after a specified timeout

Tags: notification

How to display a pop-up notification in a specified time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pop-up notification at a specified time:

```
echo 'notify-send "Go out for a coffee!"' | at 3:14PM
```

After a specified timeout:

```
echo 'notify-send "Go out for a coffee!"' | at now + 1 minutes
```

Comment: Please note that these notification bubbles fade away after a few seconds. They do not persist until you click them. I do not know what exactly the OP wants though.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you answered your own question... :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want a popup dialog window, use `zenity`, e.g. like this:

```
zenity --info --title "Your title" --text "Your text"
```

This will create a dialog window with "Your title" as title, "Your text" as body text and an <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

To delay this, you can e.g. use `sleep` and specify the delay in seconds (default), minutes (append `m`) or hours (append `h`). Here's an example that waits 30 minutes:

```
sleep 30m && zenity --info --title "Your title" --text "Your text"
```